# How to set port in KafkaEmbedded when unit testing spring-kafka consumer

Tags: java, spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test

I am using `spring-boot-starter-parent` version `1.5.0.RELEASE`, `spring-kafka` version `1.0.0.RELEASE` and `spring-kafka-test` version `1.0.0.RELEASE` in an application which consumes messages from a `Kakfa 0.9` cluster. I have a unit test for my consumer which used `KafkaEmbedded` but it fails since the broker port is picked up randomly. Is there a way I can set this broker property without changing versions? Or which versions should I use so as to not break anything?

Here is the code for the `KafkaListener` and `KafkaConsumerTest`.

#### **Listener.java**

```
@Service
public class Listener {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Listener.class);
    private CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    @KafkaListener(topics = "topic", group = "group", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void consumeClicks(@Payload String msg, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) Integer partition, @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) Integer offset, Acknowledgment ack) throws Exception {
        logger.info(msg);
        latch.countDown();
        ack.acknowledge();
    }

    public CountDownLatch getLatch() {
        return latch;
    }
}
```

#### **KafkaConsumerTest.java** (*EDIT*)

```
@DirtiesContext
@SpringBootTest(classes = {SpringApplication.class})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class KafkaConsumerTest {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaConsumerTest.class);
    private static String TEST_TOPIC = "topic";

    @ClassRule
    public static KafkaEmbedded embeddedKafka = new KafkaEmbedded(1, true, TEST_TOPIC);

    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> template;

    @Autowired
    private KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry;

    @Autowired
    private Listener listener;

    @Before
    public void init(){
        System.setProperty("spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers", embeddedKafka.getBrokersAsString());
        Map<String, Object> senderProps = KafkaTestUtils.senderProps(embeddedKafka.getBrokersAsString());
        senderProps.put("key.serializer", StringSerializer.class);
        ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, String>(senderProps);
        template = new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory);
        template.setDefaultTopic(TEST_TOPIC);
    }

    @Test
    public void testConsume() throws Exception {
        String record = "message";
        template.sendDefault(TEST_TOPIC, record);
        logger.debug("test-consume sent record {}", record);
        listener.getLatch().await(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        Assert.assertEquals(listener.getLatch().getCount(), 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use spring-kafka 1.3.9 with boot 1.5; earlier versions are no longer supported. The current boot 1.5.x version is 1.5.21.

```
@ClassRule
public static KafkaEmbedded embeddedKafka = new KafkaEmbedded(1, true, TEST_TOPIC);

static {
    embeddedKafka.setKafkaPorts(1234);
}
```

`setKafkaPorts` has been available since 1.3.

However, you are properly using the allocated random port in your test

```
Map<String, Object> senderProps = KafkaTestUtils.senderProps(embeddedKafka.getBrokersAsString());
```

To get the kafka listener to connect to the embedded broker, you can use.

```
    System.setProperty("spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers", embeddedKafka.getBrokersAsString());
```

Comment: My application is supposed to work with `Kafka 0.9` and I do not see that changing any time soon. Will the versions which you have mentioned work with that?

Comment: 0.9 is extremely old; there have been many improvements, especially [KIP-62](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-62%3A+Allow+consumer+to+send+heartbeats+from+a+background+thread) which solves rebalancing issues with slow clients, you should at least try to move to 0.10.2.0. The current version is 2.2.0. 0.9.0.0 is not even mentioned on the [compatibility page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Compatibility+Matrix). I have no idea if 1.3.9 will work with 0.9.0.0; you should try it.

Comment: Moving to 0.10.2.0 is in talks with the DevOps team at my company and would unfortunately be a slow process. I used my application with 1.3.9 with a local kafka 0.9.0.0 cluster running. The application just prints the Consumer Config values  and `o.a.k.c.u.AppInfoParser  : Kafka version : 0.11.0.2` and halts. No partition assignment takes place. I guess I will have to work with the older version for now.

Comment: You should at least upgrade to 1.0.6.RELEASE which was the last release of 1.0.x for bug fixes.

Comment: Using 1.0.6, I added `System.setProperty(..)` to the `init()` method of the test class but still KafkaListener is connecting to the broker configured in the consumerConfig for the listener container and the test fails.

Answer (score 0):

I think while application context is loaded for test, two beans are creating of type `(ProducerFactory and KafkaTemplate)`, one is with the original configs and second is with test configs, try this use different profile for tests `application-test.yml` and add bean overriding property

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding to true.
```

So that it will override the application beans with test beans and also declare `ProducerFactory` and `KafkaTemplate` as beans in test with same name as in application